# MySQL sort DESC and ASC

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table with the fields:

```
id | group_id
1  | null
2  | null
3  | null
4  | 4
5  | 4
6  | 4
7  | 7
8  | 7
9  | null
```

and I'd like to sort it to be:

```
id | group_id
9  | null
7  | 7
8  | 7
4  | 4
5  | 4
6  | 4
3  | null
2  | null
1  | null
```

So for it to be DESC by id overall, but ASC by id when they share a group_id

Thank you

Comment: I don't think is is possible with a simple order by.  Basically you can't sort one field multiple directions at the same time (some values asc and some desc). You need to rethink your problem and analyse it in a different way.

Comment: @Lamar I'll leave the question up in case someone has a clever way to solve the problem, but I'll be rethinking my problem here and trying to break it down in another way. Thanks

Comment: Can the group id be higher than the id? E.g. could `id=1, group_id=12` be a valid entry (and should it be ordered at the bottom?) And is it possible that there is an entry that has a group id for an id that has a group id `null`? (e.g. can there be `id=10, group_id=9` and `id=9, group_id = null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try It

```
Select id, group_id, coalesce(group_id, id) from table order by 3 desc, 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work:

```
SELECT id, group_id, rank
FROM (
  SELECT id, group_id, 
    @rank:=IF(group_id=@group_id,@rank,@rank+1) AS rank,
    @group_id:=group_id
  FROM MyTable CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank:=0) AS _init
  ORDER BY id DESC
) AS t
ORDER BY rank ASC, id ASC;
```

Output:

```
+----+----------+------+
| id | group_id | rank |
+----+----------+------+
|  9 |     NULL | 1    |
|  7 |        7 | 2    |
|  8 |        7 | 2    |
|  4 |        4 | 3    |
|  5 |        4 | 3    |
|  6 |        4 | 3    |
|  3 |     NULL | 4    |
|  2 |     NULL | 5    |
|  1 |     NULL | 6    |
+----+----------+------+
```

You can omit the `rank` column from the select-list of the outer query, I left it in there just to illustrate how I ranked the groups.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do the out-of-sequence ordering of the id column, but if what you need is the lowest id where the group id is shared, then updating @Lamar's answer like this would do it

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, group_id FROM table
GROUP BY group_id
ORDER BY IFNULL(group_id, 0) DESC, id DESC
```

Comment: This groups my results by group id, I don't want any "grouping" of rows, I just want them sorted within their "group" column